# JSF welcome file not properly redirecting

Tags: java, jsf-2

I am having trouble properly setting my apps welcome file to properly redirect to my home.xhtml
I tried to search within SO but I cant seem to make it work..sorry..

In my web.xml, I have these

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

My index.jsp has this

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<head>
<title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:redirect url="/faces/pages/home.xhtml"></c:redirect>
</body>
</html>
```

When I access my app:

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp
```

I am getting nothing and it is not redirecting.

What could be wrong?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416369/redirecting-using-jstl-core-redirect#answer-7416537)! ,I think it's the same type of issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Facelets XML namespace syntax in JSP. This won't work. Use JSP `@taglib` syntax.

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <c:redirect url="/faces/pages/home.xhtml"></c:redirect>
</body>
</html>
```

If you'd have explored the retrieved HTML output by rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser, then you should have noticed that the JSTL XML namespace and tag are not been parsed at all and appear plain vanilla in the HTML output.

Comment: Thanks...sorry got messed up with both JSP and JSF concept.. I am not exactly sure whats the proper way of setting welcome file in JSF

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there needs to be an index.jsf in the list too.

Comment: This is only the case if the OP attempted to use a JSF page as `<welcome-file>` whereby the `FacesServlet` URL pattern is a virtual one instead of a real one. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885874/jsf-welcome-file-not-recognized/7889247#7889247 However, in this case the OP attempted to use a plain vanilla JSP page as `<welcome-file>`.